# Проблема в использовании импортированного модуля

Tags: python, функции, импорт

Столкнулся с проблемой: разбив всего бота по модулям, импортирую его в другие такие же модули и вот проблема, в одном модуле задана переменная `dp`, я её импортирую в другой модуль и там, пока она не в функции, код её видит, но как я её отправляю в функцию, PyCharm подсказывает что я её не использую.

Вопрос-как сделать так, чтобы импортированная переменная использовалась в функции? Спасибо

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from create_bot import dp, bot
#                     ^^^^
from keyboards import kb_client
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove

# Тут между код из декораторов и т.д. и т.п.

def register_handlers_clients(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(command_start, commands=['start', 'help'])
    dp.register_message_handler(support, commands=["Режим_работы"])
    dp.register_message_handler(where_you_from, commands=["Расположение"])
```

Comment: У вас `dp` это и глобальная переменная и параметр функции. Значит, вы можете вызвать `register_handlers_clients(dp)` после того как она будет ранее инициализирована и возвращена из `create_bot`. Подобное делал в боте: импорт модуля и вызов функции установки команда: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/40914d79c7a735aa6f2bc078028f7ef1015d877c/main.py#L41 и сама функция установки команд: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/40914d79c7a735aa6f2bc078028f7ef1015d877c/bot/commands.py#L1093

Comment: попробовал объявить в функции как глоб.переменную, но  бьёт ошибку TypeError: globals() takes no arguments (1 given), мб ещё кто-нибудь что-нибудь предложит, а то я не бум бум в чём проблема или нужно ещё дополнить информацию, там между кодом декораторы, которые отвечают за ответы(1ый 2ой 3й), ошибка эта в модуле части админа, а беру эту переменную из маленького модуля где я объявил токен бота и сам вызов его прописан

Comment: Не нужно объявлять функцию как глобальную переменную. В этом же файле с `register_handlers_clients` перед запуском бота вызовите `register_handlers_clients(dp)`

Comment: Я понял, что не в этом связь!!! Я эту переменную уже вызываю и беру, поэтому она и не используется внутри модулей, ошибка в файле админ, но тут вопрос-ошибки вот такие: Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last): File ... line 381, in start_polling     raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

Comment: Вот кода часть class FSMadmin(StatesGroup):
    photo = State()
    name = State()
    description = State()
    price = State()async def make_changes_command(message: types.Message):
    global ID
    ID = message.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Что надо???")  # , reply_markup=button_case_admin)
    await message.delete()

Comment: async def cm_start(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        await FSMadmin.photo.set()
        await message.reply("Загрузи фото")

Answer (score 0):

Есть понятия глобальные переменные и локальные переменные. Переменные объявленные внутри функции называются локальными. Поэтому если вы хотите обратится именно к этой переменной то ее внутри функции можно объявить глобальной

```
def register_handlers_clients():
    global dp
    dp.register_message_handler(command_start, commands=['start', 'help'])
    dp.register_message_handler(support, commands=["Режим_работы"])
    dp.register_message_handler(where_you_from, commands=["Расположение"])
```

Ну и если будет интересно и захочется больше понять тему, то почитайте [тут](https://younglinux.info/python/local-global) )

Comment: У автора `dp` это и глобальная переменная и параметр функции. Значит, он вполне может вызвать `register_handlers_clients(dp)` после того как она будет ранее инициализирована и возвращена из `create_bot`

Comment: @gil9red Все верно, но мне показалось что за всем этим стоит некий декоратор который при каком то ивенте вызывает функцию. Но наверное я ошибся. навела меня на эту мысль фраза "PyCharm подсказывает что я её не использую"